# ETL-ORACLE DATA INTEGRATOR

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I have Some Issues with an Integration in an Oracle Datastore.
I tried to fill my datastore with data from another datastore with the same Technology (Oracle)
I have this problem issued like this : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: valeur trop grande pour la colonne "ODI"."I$_AB_ART"."LIBART" (réelle : 31, maximum : 28)
I assumed that I try to integrate data that is way too long regard the target column.
How can I avoid to blow up my flow, in others words, I want to catch those lines in a E$ table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a condition on that table.

Expand your datastore in the model and right click on Constraints --> New Condition.
On the name field, type something like "Check the length isn't too long"
and on the where clause set `LENGTH(AB_ART.LIBART) <= 28`.

You can also add a message that will be included in the Error table.

As the error table is created based on the target table, the field will be too short as well. So you will have to edit the length of that column in your datastore.

Then just turn on Flow Control in your interface and enable that condition on the Control tab.